# Доступ к любому элементу vector через итератор.

Tags: stl, c++

Допустим есть

```
vector<string> vs;
```

Содержащий:

```
[0]: "io1"
[1]: "mer2"
[2]: "qq3"
```

Как упростить доступ к каждому элементу, как в string?
Т.е. сделать такой итератор

```
iterator it=vs.begin();
```

чтобы при

```
it+=6;
```

it указывал на элемент "2"?

Comment: А почему бы не соединить всё в одну строку? Итератор `vector<string>` не разыменовывается в символ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

правильному итератору нету дела до того что хранится в ячейке  он перескакивает только между самими ячейками...

однако по идеи можно написать как то так

```
it[1][3]='3';  //"mer3"
(it[1])[3]='3';//"mer3"
```

или без особых проблем можно реализовать свой "неправильный" вектор